# Google priority for assigning page rank in domain names?

Tags: seo, pagerank

I heard something about Google has some priority for `.us` or `.name` domain names for assigning page rank to them.
For example, with the same situation for both a `.at` and `.us` domain name, the `.us` domain name will have higher page rank that `.at`.

I want to know is that correct or not?

Comment: This belongs on the Pro Webmasters Exchange, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Matt Cutts, head of the Google Web Spam team, explained a lot about TLDs in this video:
http://domainate.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/matt-cutts-discusses-new-top-level-domains-and-google/

There is no bias against TLDs, or as the article quotes:

> 1. Google will not have predisposed bias against new TLDs
>
> Matt makes it clear multiple times that Google strives to return good
>   relevant results regardless of the TLD of the domain. He even made a
>   point to indicate that Google has no bias against the recently
>   released .XXX.

Although the writer does add:

> What I think: Matt has said before they do not take TLD into account,
>   but many studies have shown that to not be true. The truth is, they
>   may not directly bias against TLDs, but factors like domain and site
>   age are factored into their algorithm. New TLDs have disadvantages in
>   both compared to established sites/domains in other extensions.

Some people later thought that Google would artifically favor new TLDs to make up for that, but here's more on that:
http://domainate.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/matt-cutts-confirms-new-tlds-will-not-get-seo-preference/

> Google has a lot of experience in returning relevant web pages,
>   regardless of the top-level domain (TLD). Google will attempt to rank
>   new TLDs appropriately, but I don’t expect a new TLD to get any kind
>   of initial preference over .com, and I wouldn’t bet on that happening
>   in the long-term either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Logically, Google has to consider tld as the same. Otherwise, all webmasters would buy `.us` tld unlike others even if they work on sites out of the United States. Moreover, I don't think Google gives more PageRank to `.us` tld than others. A website is a website despite of its tld.

In my opinion, no priority by logic.