# If my domain name ends in .ca, will people outside of Canada still be able to see it?

Tags: url

So I'm looking to start a Wordpress blog. Probably a dumb question, but the .com version of my preferred domain name was already taken. I know that here in Canada, a lot of the sites we have end in .ca. But is this extension specific to Canada? Will people in the US and other parts of the world still be able to access my site if it ends in .ca? And if they can, will it hurt my search results?

Comment: Yes anyone can access your site dont worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not specific to just Canada. Yes, people all over the world will be able to see it.

Comment: Well that is good to know. But will it negatively effect search results? Like does google give preferential treatment to sites ending in .com? Because I want to maximize my readership and don't want a silly thing like the domain name to be a limiting factor.

Comment: Nope. Google has a specific algorithm to determine what sites come up first, and TLDs are NOT factored into that. Now depending on how your site is linked and how OTHER PEOPLE (not Google) see your site, it might effect the value of your site based on how many times it is or isn't linked. Here's a good answer with info on Google and TLDs (Top Level Domains, ie: .ca): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526151/google-priority-for-assigning-page-rank-in-domain-names

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can access your site and it will not hurt the search results.